# Missing methods and constants in OpenGL ES 2.0 headers

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, opengl-es

I'm starting to learn to OpenGL for using it with iOS. I'm wondering why methods like `glMatrixMode` or constants like `GL_PROJECTION` are there in `<OpenGLES/ES1/gl.h>`, but not in `<OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>`. Why? Are you enforced to write your own shaders when using OpenGL ES 2.0 instead of 1.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Fixed function pipeline, including the built in  matrices were completely taken out of OpenGL ES 2.0 so constants like GL_PROJECTION, and functions such as glPushMatrix, glRotate, glMatrixMode etc have been removed.

This change requires you to write shaders and pass/calculate your own model and projection matrices to it. While ES 2 provides you with much more flexibility it also makes it very difficult to work with older code and get started as a beginner.

If you don't have a full understanding of how the projection and model matrices, you may want to stick with ES 1.

A Presentation with a further explanation can be found [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=5&sqi=2&ved=0CDAQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.amd.com%2Fgpu_assets%2FGDC06-GLES_Tutorial_Day-Munshi-OpenGLES_Overview.pdf&rct=j&q=gdc%20pdf%20OpenGL%20ES%202.0%20fragment%20OpenGL%20ES%201.1%2B&ei=Q9PyTLX6LYHEsAOD0MjwCw&usg=AFQjCNG51PAC_baVHQQRDJmtNaKDCLRpzw&sig2=wPYJC3iSQE9cnjHbmrYFTg&cad=rja)

Comment: I actually just want to use OpenGL to render precalculated pixels fast onto the screen. So I should just stick with ES1.1?

Comment: Tough do you need a 3D projection?

Comment: Could they be represented by a texture?

Comment: No I don't need a 3D projection.

Comment: I would just go with OGLES1 unless it is something you can do in a shader passed as a texture.